# How to make a Donate version of my app?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create Free/Paid versions of Application from same code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590203/create-free-paid-versions-of-application-from-same-code)

Im trying to make a donate version of my app on Google Play, but when I go to upload it, it gives me an error that there is already an application with the package name. Is there an easy way to make a duplicate of the app and have a different package name? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to handle this, that I've been seeing more and more of, just create a simple app that costs whatever your donation amount is, and link your users to it. It will be something simple, like a thank you card, or even no activity at all. Just remind your users to keep it for more than 20 minutes before deleting it, or it will be refunded.

Answer (score 0):

Google Play uses package names to identify different applications, so you would need to change the package name. If you use Eclipse, it is quite simple to refactor the package name (e.g. if your package name is com.example.test, change it to com.example.test.donate), and then build it again.