# How to implement pro version android app

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-developer-api

So I am making this app . I wanna have an app for free and a paid version too. I tried searching on google on how to implement it, but I couldnt find any proper threads. From some research I see In-app purchases is an option , but I'm not entirely clear. Can someone explain to me how this can be done? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create Free/Paid versions of Application from same code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590203/create-free-paid-versions-of-application-from-same-code)

Comment: Also see about product flavors. https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html

Answer (score 5):

You have to use flavors to achieve what you want. You need to have two different application id for each version. It will create *.apk with different id for free and paid version and therefore you will be able to upload two separate apps on Google Play.

```
android {

    productFlavors {           
        free {
            applicationId "com.myapp.free"
        }
        paid {
            applicationId "com.myapp.paid"
        }
    }   

}
```

Free version is build with:

```
gradlew assembleFreeRelease
```

Paid version is build with:

```
gradlew assemblePaidRelease
```

Your actual package can be different than application id:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.myapp">
</manifest>
```

In code you can check what flavor is used:

```
if (BuildConfig.FLAVOR.equals("free")) {
    //do sth only for free version   
}
```