# How to organize a project with subprojects in Intellij?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, project

i have developed an android app (my first one) which i now want to split in different "flavors". Like "free", "plus" and "premium". So decided to work with a base (a library project) and move all different code to the subprojects.

What is the best way to handle a project with a base module and some "flavor" modules?

I tried to a create a project with a library module. Then created two modules with content root and module file location set to *project_root*/Projekte/*module_name*. But i get the modules within *project_root*/*module_name*. Only the .iml was in the chosen folder.

What did i do wrong?

Comment: This may help you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740319/bulk-publishing-of-android-apps/4740728#4740728