# Why two different app using aviary sdk not installed in same device?

Tags: android, aviary, google-play

I have developed two apps using Aviary SDK, Both have **different keys.**
The app links are :

[**Photo Sketcher**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hytomobi.photosketcher)

[**Photo Editor**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hytomobi.photoeditor)

I am facing an strange issue while installing both apps from play store. If one installed already in a device then while installing other, It's giving me ***duplicate provider authority***.

But I have created different secret keys for both apps and put those respectively. Even though I am getting this error.

How can I resolve this issue ?

Comment: Can you post the Manifest files for each of the two apps?

Comment: Yeah sure! Give me a minute :P

Comment: This thread will be help I guess. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420130/android-duplicate-provider-authority-problem

Comment: Thanks IBunny, I cant update my code now, will do at night and will let you know. :)

Comment: @Code-Guru I wanted to thank you, but you were not in the room ,but here I can, Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check Manifest file of both apps, you have probably put same authority (eg. `android:authorities=com.exaple` ) for both of your provider. Change and make it unique for both app. You can use package name like`android:authorities="{your.package.name}.YourProvider"`.

Comment: Yes! that was my issue, I found it earlier. Thanks anyway :)