# Content Provider Example using two android applications

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I want to `insert` or `delete` the values in another android applications database from my current android application.

I searched a lot. Everybody saying that use "`content provider`" its not used with two applications all used with in a application.

Comment: Did you see this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306639/multiple-apps-use-same-content-provider

Comment: How came you can say, one can not use another application db. U always using contacts/gallery databases and many more.

Comment: http://www.linkedin.com/groups/Is-it-possible-one-application-76373.S.48437477

Comment: Now it working perfectly. Below answer is good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here i found some examples/tutorial for you, Please have a look , below tuts include everything you can do to create content provider.

[Android Fundamentals: Working With Content Providers .](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_content-providers/)

[example1](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/13/writing-your-own-contentprovider/)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have a database and a content provider in your application....
You can use the database of other application if it is exported. To export your database you just need to set the value of android:exported attribute of Provider tag to true in android.manifest file

```
    <provider
        android:exported="true"
        android:name="<content provider>"
        android:authorities="<content provider authority>" >
    </provider>
```

In the other application's Android.Manifest file provide the permission to access the content provider.

see the links below for more information[Content Providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)
and [Using Content Providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/security.html)