# Updating SQLite from external App on Android

Tags: android, sqlite

*If this has been answered already, kindly redirect me to the correct post.*

Here is the problem:

I have 2 android apps which are under development. I have a requirement where one App (App A) will update a certain field in SQLite DB> Table 'A' and the other App (App B) has to read this entry. The DB will be created and maintained thru App B and not App A.

Is this possible? If so, how?

If more information is required, kindly let me know.

Thanks in advance

Ram

Comment: check out this link   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407798/content-provider-example-using-two-android-applications

Answer (score 0):

if you share the apps' user id you will be able to use the same database in both apps: [sharedUserId](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#sharedUserId)

Answer (score 0):

If you want your app data to be shared across all other apps then it will be better option to go for content providers instead of using sqlite.