# How to create common Content Provider for multiple applications

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I have a number of android applications, I need a storage common to all these applications , but creation of common storage should be dynamically from the first app which uses/launches from device(first app from the list of app).

For example , if we have applications named A, B, C. When A is launched , it should check whether the DB exists, and creates it if it doesn't exist already. Next when B is launched since the storage is already created by A, B need not create it, it can just fetch the data or add data to common storage. 
Can content provider do this? But how to define the URI , we are not sure which app is going to create the content provider.

Comment: [i don't think if it's possible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306639/multiple-apps-use-same-content-provider) ... you can try make app D which is/has a ContentProviver only ... or one off those app(A,B or C) should be "master" app with CP ...

Comment: Thanks Selvin.. I am going to implement your first alternative, though its not an actual alternative to the problem.