# Adding multiple file providers in Android application

Tags: android, android-manifest, aar, android-fileprovider

guys, I am working on an android application for which I need external application dependency(.aar file)
library application has its own file provider and my application have its own.

library work well when I run it as a separate app but when I include it my application then camera functionality not working. I get the following error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

following the manifest file of the application

```
<provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
```

and the following is a manifest file of the lib module

```
<provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.ma.bot.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
```

both application and lib module have different package name how I add this 2 file providers into the application
I also try including multiple file providers using, but I get XML parse error on app compilation.

```
android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider;com.ma.bot.provider"
```

how to solve this.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Guys I found solution on this link
[Possible to use multiple authorities with FileProvider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43175014/possible-to-use-multiple-authorities-with-fileprovider)

Basically problem is my library and application have same name android.support.v4.content.FileProvider so it colliding in manifest merger, to avoid this I need to defile empty class extending File provider and use it provider name

```
<provider
            android:name="com.MAG.MAGFileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider;"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
```

and declare class like this

```
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
public class MAGFileProvider extends FileProvider
{
    //we extend fileprovider to stop collision with chatbot library file provider
    //this class is empty and used in manifest
}
```

Comment: it worked for me. when I am using this for library
android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"  android:authorities="com.library.provider" 
and 
this in main app manifest android:name="com.MAG.MAGFileProvider"            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider;"

Comment: where does the class file get created?

Comment: best answer ever!