# Opening pdf file from documents of internal storage in Android has issue

Tags: android, kotlin, pdf, android-intent, permissions

I am creating an Android app that I save some files in Documents of internal storage and then I want to open that pdf file in app programmatically. I have searched a lot and now I can open Documents but I can't open the pdf file directly. What should I change in the code? please help me.
In Manifest I added this:

```
 <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider1"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
```

As provider_paths.xml I have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

And as code in activity I have this:

```
 val fileName = "order5.pdf"
        val file = File(File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"Documents"), fileName)
        val fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.example.repo.provider1", file)
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply {
            setDataAndType(fileUri, "application/pdf")
            flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
        }
        startActivity(intent)
```

File is identified correctly. I think I should make change in intent.

Comment: ACTION_GET_CONTENT is to let the user select a file. It does not need a FileProvider. It does not need any permission. It does not open a file. It only selects one. You messed it all up.

Comment: `If I use ACTION_VIEW, it will show all pdf files of device.` No. Dont think so.

Comment: `want to open that pdf file in app programmatically. ` Ok. But in your own app or in another app? A pdf viewer app for instance?

Comment: I want to open it in pdf viewer of device

Comment: `creating an Android app that I save some files in Documents` Unclear. Tell how these files landed there. Did your app create them?

Comment: Yes, has it difference? One pdf file in documents is wanted to open, whether I have made it in my app or it is made in another app.

Comment: Yes the scenario is different then.

Comment: These files are made in my app

Comment: Then use ACTION_VIEW with uri from FileProvidet and READ permission. Throw away ACTION_GET_CONTENT.

Comment: All notes is shown not the desired pdf

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by 'All notes are shown'. And further you should have posted your new code.

Comment: To view a PDF, use `ACTION_VIEW`. FWIW, I cover how to view a PDF in [this section](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-files-005.html) of [this free book of mine](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/).

Comment: My code hasn't changed except of ACTION_VIEW I put instead of ACTION_GET_CONTENT, I meaned samsung notes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found my problem. I have two providers in manifest and it made conflict. See this great question and answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53512552/12478830