# Can't install because provider name com.iceteck.silicompressor.provider (in package MyPackagename2) is already used by Package1

Tags: c#, android, exception, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

my App is not installing in my android device if another app(that app also used silicompressor nuget) is installed on my device. I have checked out with `manifest file,android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"` and both apps having different `android:authorities` name only. What is the actual problem causing this exception. Please help to resolve this Error using xamarin forms.

> Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException:Failure[INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER: Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/MyPackagename2-FNVNvrTmReyC06yRui516g==: Can't install because provider name com.iceteck.silicompressor.provider (in package MyPackagename2) is already used by Package1

Comment: According to your error message, I guess that you may use multiple authorities with FileProvider, I search some info that you can take a look, may be helpful to you: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/android-sdk/pull/83 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43175014/possible-to-use-multiple-authorities-with-fileprovider/43444164#43444164

Answer (score 1):

By any chance are you using any Android X library in your xamarin forms application? Is silicompressor a library that works with the android content file provider

Comment: https://github.com/Tourenathan-G5organisation/SiliCompressor/pull/95  I got that error while using 2.2.1 they fixed this 2.2.2 nuget update.at the same time, it works with xamarin.forms 4.2, if i try update xamarin.forms to 4.6 then its not updating and throwing   Version conflict detected for Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations 28.0.0.3. any possibility to work silicompressor with xamarin.forms 4.6?

Comment: @shankarkrishna Xamarin forms 4.6 supports androidX out of the box. If you want use xamarin forms 4.6. You may need to add androidx nugget packages for the compatibility for the latest version. Here are the following packages you need: `Xamarin.AndroidX.Migration` this package will help to migrate library dependencies that use android support library to android x. You may also need to keep reference for the support library: `Xamarin.Android.Support.v4` and `Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat` which may help in your application to compile successfully. The migration will need refactoring.