# Using multiple authorities with FileProvider

Tags: android, xamarin

[Possible Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43175014/possible-to-use-multiple-authorities-with-fileprovider)

I have a project using 2 different libraries that require `ContentProvider`:

```
<provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" 
          android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider" 
          android:exported="false" 
          android:grantUriPermissions="true">
          
      <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" 
                     android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
</provider>
```

However, for authorities, one library instructs to use `${applicationId}.fileprovider` whilst the other one instructs `${applicationId}.provider`.

According to the Android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html), `android:authorities` is a list whose values can be separated by a semicolon.

> android:authorities="list"

By that logic, doing something like this:

```
 <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" 
              android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider;${applicationId}.provider" 
              android:exported="false" 
              android:grantUriPermissions="true">
              
          <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" 
                         android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
```

should work, however, this causes my app to crash with the following error message:

```
Unable to get provider androidx.core.content.FileProvider: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find meta-data for provider with authority my.packagename.fileprovider;my.packagename.provider
```

I have taken a look at similar questions but the answers do not address this.
How do we successfully specify multiple authorities for the same provider?

Comment: Im using libraries, if i specify one authority, the other library won't work hence the need to specify both authorities

Comment: @blackapps I've edited the question and removed the spaces because even without the spaces, it still does not work

Answer (score 0):

Using FileProvider with multiple authorities i found this possible.

Changed

```
"${applicationId}.fileprovider"
```

To

```
"${applicationId}.fileprovider;${applicationId}.fileproviderxyz"
```

And all worked as before.

Tested on Android 12 emulator and Android 10 device.

But... that was without changing any code.

As soon as i used the second authority for FileProvider.getUriForFile() there was this IllegalArgumentException.

Instead using multiple authorities for own ContentProvider derived class is ok.

Try: define two providers for FileProvider in manifest file with a single authority each.