# Getting package name conflict with different application ids of the same app

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0, android-package-managers

I have an app with two flavors, each with a unique application id, according to [the docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id) this is how to install both versions of the app on the same phone. But I keep getting [the package name conflict error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gB2ig.png) while I try to install either of them while the other one is already installed

Flavor settings

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.kc.mb.vr"
    multiDexEnabled true
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 14
    setProperty("archivesBaseName", "vr4.25.1")
}

flavorDimensions "default"


productFlavors {
    dev {
        versionName "4.25.1"
        applicationId "com.kc.mb.vr.dev"        
        dimension "default"

    }
    prod {
        applicationId "com.kc.mb.vr"        
        versionName "3.1.2"
        dimension "default"
    }
}
```

After installing, I checked with the package name viewer that shows the app with the  dev flavor has a packagename + ".dev" and the one with prod has a different package name. But both of them can not be installed together.

Is there any step that I might have missed ?

Comment: Is it possible an app with that package name already exists on your device? Maybe with a different signature or even a different app altogether?

Comment: @TheWanderer couldn't find anything like that, I will update the code to show more config

Comment: Its an issue with the file-provider authority. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306639/multiple-apps-use-same-content-provider

Answer (score 0):

For example,in your dev flavor,delete `applicationId "com.kc.mb.vr"` and add following code:
 `applicationIdSuffix ".dev"`
then your dev's package name will be "com.kc.mb.vr.dev"

Comment: Thanks, but the issue was caused by having one authority with the file provider

Comment: Sorry,I made a mistake,my answer is really not for your problem,can you post your FileProvider's configuration or some error log when you install your second app?

Comment: @Aolphin I fixed it. I have provided a link to my actual issue in the comment above